# Change URL without losing access to site

Tags: url, rwd, magento-1.9

I almost finished my magento site. Now I want to edit my base url since I got the standard: `http://192.168.2.106/magento/` URL. If I try to change my base URL via backend ->System -> Configuration -> Web - secure/unsecure base-url to for example: `http://192.168.2.106/abc/` I'm getting an object not founded! error 404. How can I change my base URL ?

Comment: ok rename your local.xml and install again

Comment: Please take your time to accept an answer if it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

In the worst case you can just edit the table core_config_data and fix the url there.

Comment: Already tried but still doens't work

Comment: he is changing the default url for the magento site from  magento to abc, so this will also require some web server configuration changes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to rename the `magento` directory to `abc` if this should be your base URL.

Answer (score 0):

Before you change your base url, make sure you disable your cache and flush out your cache storage.

If you are using the filesystem as the storage cache (the default) then these commands will empty all the cache folders that might have cached the old url

```
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf media/css*
rm -rf media/js*
```

Now change your base url, enable and refresh your caches.

If you change the path from the default root / to something else like /abc you will also either need to edit your web server config to make an alias or rewrite rule for the default magento directory or depending on how you have configured the web server root folder move/rename the magento root folder itself.

You can also try changing the .htaccess rewrite base from / to /abc.